# Big-O notation calculation, O(n) * O(log n) = O(n log n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I need to design an algorithm that is able to do some calculations in given O notation. It has been some time since I last calculated with O notation and I am a bit confused on how to add different O notations together.

```
O(n) * O(log n) = O(n log n)

O(n) + O(n) = O(2n) = O(n)

O(n) * O(log n) + O(n log n) = O(n log n) + O(n log n) = O(n log n)
```

Are these correct? What other rules have I overlooked?

Comment: I have edited the title (formerly `O(n) + O(log n) = O(n log n)`) to be correct now.

Comment: My comment is tangential, but some may find it interesting.  The notation O(log n) occasions more confusion than almost anything I have seen in computer science.  Almost everybody seems to believe that O(log n) differs from O(1) -- except that it doesn't.  You can prove that it doesn't by application of L'Hospital's rule.  One should hesitate to abandon a clean algorithm to improve O(log n) to O(1), even if n == 1 billion.  The gains simply aren't there (you can run the numbers if you don't believe me), whereas the gains are indeed there if the abandoned algorithm is, say, O(sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_notation#Properties) for multiplication is really simple:

```
O(f) * O(g) = O(f * g)
```

The sum of two `O` terms is harder to calculate if you want it to work for arbitrary functions.
However, if `f ∈ O(g)`, then `f + g ∈ O(g)`.

Therefore, your calculations are correct, but your original title is not;

```
O(n) + O(log n) = O(n)
```

Comment: Thank you, i though so, but got a bit confused when trying to juggle the algorithm :D thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it ... *incorrect*? That is, `max(n, log n)` => `n`?

Comment: Yes, the relation in the title of the post is incorrect: `O(n) + O(log n) = O(n log n)`. But the relation he made in the post is correct: `O(n) * O(log n) = O(n log n)`.

Comment: @sch Oops, the rules are correct, but the conclusion is not, is what I should have said. It is hardly fair to say "correct" in this case.

Comment: Updated the answer. Since `O(log(n))` is a subset of `O(n)`, `O(n) + O(log n) = O(n)`

Comment: I have edited the title (formerly `O(n) + O(log n) = O(n log n)`) to be correct now.

Comment: Your definition of `max` is wrong. If `O(f) + O(g) = O(max(f, g))`, then `max` has to be defined *pointwise*. Consider f(n) = n, g(n) = 1 for even n and n^2 else. Then O(max(f, g)) = O(h), where h(n) = n for even n, and n^2 else.

Comment: @WolframH Doesn't `O(n)` allow "for all `n > N`"?

Comment: @WolframH Yeah, that definition was overly informal. Rectified it by defining max over the sets. It's technically correct, but makes it harder to read imho.

Comment: @pst I don't see how that would make a difference in my example.

Comment: @phihag It's still not right. O(f) + O(g) need not be O(f) or O(g), and you still seem to state that.

Comment: @WolframH You're right. I've restricted the definition to monotonic functions. It's correct for those, right?

Comment: @phihag It's wrong for all g, f where neither f = O(g) nor g = O(f). Take f(n) = n!, g(n) = sqrt(n) * n! for n odd, g(n) = g(n-1) for n even.

Comment: You're totally right. Sorry, I should've seen that. Changed to the union, with an explanation.

Comment: Still not correct. `O(x) + O(y) = O(x + y)`. If `|f| <= A*x` and `|g| <= B*y`, then obviously `|f+g| <= max(A,B)*(x+y)`. Conversely, if `|h| <= C*(x+y)`, let `f(t) = sign(h(t))*C*x(t)` if `|h(t)| > C*x(t)` and `f(t) = h(t)` otherwise, `g(t) = h(t) - f(t)`. Then `|f| <= C*x` by construction, and `|g| <= C*y` because 1. if `h(t) < -C*x(t)`, then `|g(t)| = |h(t) - (-C*x(t))| = |h(t)| - C*x(t) <= C*y(t)`; 2. if `-C*x(t) <= h(t) <= C*x(t)`, then `|g(t)| = 0 <= C*y(t)` and 3. if `h(t) > C*x(t)`, then `|g(t)| = |h(t) - C*x(t)| = |h(t)| - C*x(t) <= C*y(t)`.

Comment: I removed the third assertion, which was irrelevant to the question and indeed overly simplified, and linked to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: This answer links to the Wikipedia article, but still makes up its own (wrong) rules for the sum... -1

Comment: @WolframH Completely rewrote it.

Comment: Why don't you just write "For f = O(g): O(f) + O(g) = O(g)"?